# Can I use a loop to execute the same function call multiple times on incrementing element Id's?

Tags: javascript, loops

Right now I have 2 functions called `showElement(elementId)` and `hideElement(elementId)`. I use these to hide and display rows in a table based on what a user clicks.

I have a submit button for an area that takes in about 30 rows and looks like the following

```
function hideGeneralSection {
  hideElement('gen1');
  hideElement('gen2');
  hideElement('gen3');
  hideElement('gen4');
  ...
  hideElement('gen35');
}
```

I was content with keeping it like this but then I realized I wanted to add in about 5 sections, each with show and hide for all the rows AND I made two new functions that gray out elements / enable them.

In java for example you can print a string with something that looks like the following: `("showElement('gen%i')",5)`. Is there anything like that in javascript so that I could just make a loop that spits out `showElement('genINTEGER')` in 3 lines instead of 30 something each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your function's argument is a string, you can just concatenate a loop variable on the end of the root "gen" like so:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 35; i++) showElement('gen' + i);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, you answered so quickly I actually have to wait a couple more minutes before approving your answer =p.

Thank you!